# deluxetable format all jumbled inside ApJ format

Tags: tables

I have followed an [example on here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147879/problems-with-deluxetable) and just pasted the code into my paper to see if it would work. I then compile and it all seems to work but the output I get out looks like the following:

[image: Jumbled Deluxetable]

A friend on Linux compiles this and the table format is fine. Is there any formatting prescription/package I should be using to fix the table? I am using the following header:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter]{emulateapj}
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue
}
```

The table does appear properly when I use `\documentclass[11pt,letter]{aastex}` but this is not the format I desire - I want `emulateapj`. I've also tried `\documentclass[iop,revtex4]{emulateapj}` with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you complete your header to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: While waiting for a MWE, one thought looking at the output is that you might just need to compile a second time.  The implementation is based on `longtable` which can need several passes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have

```
\tablewidth{\textwidth}
```

which is of course wrong when typesetting in a two column format. If you want the table as wide as a column, use

```
\tablewidth{\columnwidth}
```